# Webview with iframe on Android, link position not freshed in scroll

Tags: android, iframe, webview, scroll

I am working an Android App that has 3 iframes,

1. top (title)
2. bottom-left (navigation)
3. bottom-right (data)

and user can press on a certain picture in the iframe 3 to show a pop-up window for detail info.

e.g. At the coordinate (100, 100) in iframe 3, I have picture1 that has a hyperlink to detail1. It make sense when I start the app and press (100,100), detail1 would pop-up. But the strange thing is that even if I scroll (downwards) to anther page which the picture1 is not in sight, I press relative coordinate (100,100), detail1 still pops up.

It seems the first-screen position was cached and not being refreshed when scroll. I tested to I make it a simple HTML page without iframe, no such problem. Anybody came up the similar problem and can share your experience?

Comment: I am desperate for that, appreciate anyone can help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have encounted the same problem.

The project I work on loads a long document with form elements in an IFRAME. As long as the IFRAME isn't scrolled, everything is fine, but if it is scrolled, the events gets send to the wrong coordinates of the sub-document in the frame.

My theory on the problem is that the iframe computes the event coordinates relative to the origin (top left corner), but "forgets" to add the scrolling offset before propagating the event to the contained document. This theory is based on having a lot of input fields, scrolling a controlled amount and observing how the fields (checkboxes) are activated.

I have also reported this as http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25766

Comment: And it seems to exist in android 3.0 as well, without android devs paying much attention: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19625

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is out of date and nobody is interested on this solution but, I faced this problem and I got a workaround to achieve the desired behaviour.

In my case, I have a div that wrap the iframe like that:

```
 <div id="iFrameContainer">
    <iframe frameborder="0" id='iframe' width='100%' src=''  style="display: none;"    onload="loadIframe();"> </iframe>  
 </div>
```

Then in my css

```
    #iFrameContainer {
     overflow: auto;
    }
```

And then, in a JS code (and the most important) is to set the heigh value of the iframe according to the content of the iframe.

```
    resizeIframe(document.getElementById('iFrameContainer'));

    function resizeIframe(obj) {
      console.log("RESIZING");
      obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
      obj.contentWindow.document.body.style.overflow ="none";
    }
```

Hope you still want the solution